# Mongoose model.create() responds empty or do not responde

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, request, schema

I created a small project with node+express+mongodb

This is where i call the create user:

```js
const express = require("express");
const User = require("../models/user");

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.create(req.body);
    return res.send({ user });
  } catch (e) {
    return res.status(400).send({ error: "Registration failed" });
  }
});

module.exports = app => app.use("/auth", router);
```

and here is the Schema for the user:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
    select: false
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

But when o make the resquest, it nevers get a response, it waits forever. And when o take out the await from the request, it gets an empty response { "user": {}}

I'm kind lost looking the mongoose documentation (the ideia is to make a simple rest api, i'm used with python, but looking to learn node)

Comment: I think the error is in your req.body payload. could you please add what is the payload you are sending as req.body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new user from User Model as follows:

```
    const express = require("express");
    const User = require("../models/user");

    const router = express.Router();

    router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
      try {
        var user = new User(request.body);
        var result = await user.create();
        return res.send({ result });
      } catch (e) {
        return res.status(400).send({ error: "Registration failed" });
      }
    });

module.exports = app => app.use("/auth", router);
```

Comment: in my case I can not use keyword new it gets error "is not a constructor"